# increasing imagemagick memory/disk limits

Tags: imagemagick

I find that I cannot increase imagemagick's memory/map/disk limits above their current values:

```
$ identify -list resource
Resource limits:
  Width: 16KP
  Height: 16KP
  Area: 128MP
  Memory: 256MiB
  Map: 512MiB
  Disk: 1GiB
  File: 768
  Thread: 4
  Throttle: 0
  Time: unlimited
```

While I can decrease the limits from the above values, I cannot increase them:

```
$ identify -limit memory 128MiB -list resource | grep Mem
  Memory: 128MiB
$ identify -limit memory 512MiB -list resource | grep Mem
  Memory: 256MiB
$ MAGICK_DISK_LIMIT=0.2GiB identify -list resource | grep Disk
  Disk: 204.8MiB
$ MAGICK_DISK_LIMIT=2GiB identify -list resource | grep Disk
  Disk: 1GiB
```

How can increases above the default values be made? My system has 8 GB of RAM, 8 GB of swap, and, at least on certain partitions, hundreds of GB of available disk space.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This [page](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/resources.php) explains how limits can be specified in a file `policy.xml`, which is looked for in several directories:

```
$MAGICK_CONFIGURE_PATH
$PREFIX/etc/ImageMagick-7 
$PREFIX/share/ImageMagick-7 
$XDG_CACHE_HOME/ImageMagick
$HOME/.config/ImageMagick
<client path>/etc/ImageMagick
```

where `$PREFIX` depends on your distribution, and might be `/usr/local`.
Replace 7 by the major version of your release, seen in the output of `identify --version`.
My distributed policy file `/etc/ImageMagick-6/policy.xml` has all the values commented out (with xml `<!-- -->`), eg

```
<!-- <policy domain="resource" name="memory" value="2GiB"/> -->
```

so the limits on memory, for example, are 3.7499GiB for 4G of ram.

Comment: A note for future readers: `policy.xml `